# Open applications every 30 mins on mac

Tags: macos

I am looking for a way to open my email client app on my mac every 30 mins. This is so that I am not distracted doing my work but every 30 mins look at my emails. Should I set up a cron job? I tried to use the launch tool on mac osx but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to check for new emails every 30 minutes, or open and close down the email program entirely?

Most email clients have the option to check for new messages every x time. You can just minimize the program in between.

As far as automaticly opening the client every x time you can use a cronjob to do so. Besides from this, I can't imagine that Mac (not a Mac user) wouldn't have a more consumer friendly tool for creating recurring tasks.

Comment: Well, it will be all my communication tools. So I want it to open slack, skype and my email client. I will then go through my messages and then close all the applications.